# How can I get details about an steam appid from steam web API?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

so I wanted to know if anyone knows how to get details (like description, genre, tags, ...) on an steam appid using web API? or an easy site to scrape the data from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Steam Web API does not have methods to do this.

Use the [unofficial Steam Storefront API](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/User:RJackson/StorefrontAPI) instead. Try it:

```
https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=10
```

Comment: @Kasi You can accept my answer and upvote it please:)